# deploy flex application on tomcat server (not localhost) with blazeDS starting in eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, deployment, flash-builder, blazeds

I have a locally developed flex application which i would now deploy on a live server. Those are the constraints:

- Using blazeDS with java code

  - Code depends on other project in eclipse
  - the other project has several dependencies on 3rd party libs.
- Using some external flash .swc libs
- some web.xml settings are custom

In another post the structure for the exported folder is explained:

[What needs to be in a .war file to deploy a Flex application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263228/what-needs-to-be-in-a-war-file-to-deploy-a-flex-application)

In the default usage of Flash Builder i can create a release build and store it somewhere. This will create the release version of all the flex content.

I now want to export the .war file within the export function of eclipse and here comes the problem:

1. How can i exclude the files not needed in the war file. There is a debug build of the flex app and some other files i do not need.
2. How can i automatically insert the dependend libs of the imported eclipse project to the web-inf lib folder. When i try to export the release the function sais that the imported eclispe project cannot be created by the release process but it is within the lib folder of web-inf on .war export except the dependencies.
3. Can somebody point me to the documententation of flashbuilder regarding exportinmg and deployment.

Maybe i need an ANT process to optimize that. What do you think?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everything you just said, there are 2 ways of doing it:

1) Create it manually by copy pasting what you need in your war file into a folder, removing what isn't needed then create said war file using command line.

2) Create an automation script that does it all for you.  This could be ANT or Maven (I personally prefer Maven for it's dependency management).

The latter is the enterprise way of doing it because it's easy to run ("mvn clean install war") and you can attach the script to an automation engine (like hudson, bamboo, teamcity, etc) which can then compile/test/deploy everything something is committed to your source control.

Comment: But isn't there a User friendly flash builder export.

Comment: Maybe there is, can't say I've ever used it.  Do you really want to spend time working on an eclipse based export and have to do the same for all developers on the team?  What happens when something change? then all developers need to change their settings.  Much easier to just update the maven file, update and run file.  trust me.

Comment: Remember, user friendly is relative. If developers are the users, then they can probably handle running a script from a terminal.